# GitLab release-job creates a release where asset is artifacts.zip instead of concrete file

Tags: docker, gitlab, release, cicd, artifacts

I have this script:

```
release-job:  # Valid release section within the job
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest              
  script:
    - | 
      echo "Getting Artifact Link"
      ARTIFACT_URL=$(cat artifact_url.txt | tr -d '\r')
      ARTIFACT_URL=${ARTIFACT_URL:2}
      echo "BIGProjectSetup.msi download URL - $ARTIFACT_URL"
      ASSETS_LINK="{\"name\":\"BIGProjectSetup.msi\",\"url\":\"$ARTIFACT_URL\",\"link_type\":\"package\"}"
      echo "Assets link JSON - $ASSETS_LINK"
      echo "Creating Release"
      release-cli create --name "BIGProject" --tag-name "TestRelease" --description "New version of BIGProject" --assets-link "$ASSETS_LINK"
  dependencies:
    - packaging
  needs:
    - packaging
```

The issue I have is that in the Deploy->Releases section after clicking on download link my downloader starts to download "artifacts.zip" instead of BIGProjectSetup.msi. The link is correctly used and formatted and it looks like this:

```
https://code.com/bigproject/big-project/-/jobs/17106/artifacts/download?file=build_artifacts/BIGProjectSetup.msi
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks a lot